# SNL line about getting a donut

Tags: phrase-meaning, jokes, offensive-language

Ok. so English is my 2nd language... I watch this episode of SNL. And people are cracking up.. But I can't get my head around why "Can a bitch get a donut?” is funny and who is Keven Roberts (Googling reveals he's a businessman).

The skit can be found at [this link](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/larry-david-snl-episode-saturday-night-live-kevin-roberts-sketch).

I've been googling long time to get any hints.. but no clue yet..
Please help?

Comment: Not every native speaker thinks the material on SNL is funny; some of it's terrible. To each their own.

Comment: What is this SNL?

Comment: @SovereignSun It's short for Saturday Night Live, a long-running sketch comedy series.

Answer (score 3):

The character of Kevin Roberts is not a representation of a real person, just a 'typical' annoying person from the 1980s (we get this from the oversized-cellphone, fashion and the music he dances to).

The **joke** of the entire sketch is that the FBI shooting range is training cadets to quickly distinguish "good guys" from "bad guys", but you have annoying people like Kevin Roberts who aren't *evil*, but are irritating and people don't like them, so it is a moral dilemma whether or not to shoot them.

A lot of the things that Kevin Roberts says are egotistical and pretentious. He refers to himself as a "bitch", suggesting through outdated street slang that he is a tough guy. When he asks "*can a bitch get a donut?*" *he* is "the bitch" and is loudly demanding that an underling bring him a donut. Later in the sketch, someone does bring him a donut.

The lines he delivers are not jokes or puns, just absurd and build up an irritating character which is what some are finding funny.

The only other relevance I can see about asking for a donut is that at the end of the sketch Kevin is revealed to be the designer of the FBI shooting range, so is presumably a past FBI agent himself. It is a widely-used generalisation that US police like donuts.

Comment: Gosh, it's the best explanation all around. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a common phrase, nor would it be funny in any typical setting. In the skit, I think people are laughing specifically because it is just such a goofy and random phrase that doesn't fit the situation at all. And it's a weird character too, saying weird things, that makes the whole thing funny. Of course with any humor, many people may not find this skit funny at all.